# Граница многоугольника / border radius кнопки

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Я пытаюсь придать границе форму многоугольника, как показано на изображении ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, который я пробовал, приведен ниже.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

.p-button{
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #5344c6;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  border-radius: 27px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
```

```html
<a class="p-button" href="">Explore The Tech</a>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Polygon border / border radius of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68507558/7394871) от участника  [@Foss Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16514860/foss-bytes).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68507558/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Используйте clip-path

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');

.p-button{
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #5344c6;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-size:40px;
  --h:45px; /* это половина высоты, отрегулируйте ее в соответствии с вашим кодом */
  clip-path:polygon(
    0 50%,
    calc(0.134*var(--h))  25%,   /* 0.134 = 1 - cos(30)   */
    calc(  0.5*var(--h))  6.7%,  /* 6.7% = 0.134/2 * 100% */
    var(--h) 0,
    calc(100% - var(--h)) 0,
    calc(100% - 0.5*var(--h))   6.7%,
    calc(100% - 0.134*var(--h)) 25%,
    100% 50%,
    calc(100% - 0.134*var(--h)) 75%,
    calc(100% - 0.5*var(--h))   93.3%, /* 93.3% = 100% - 6.7% */
    calc(100% - var(--h)) 100%,
    var(--h) 100%,
    calc(  0.5*var(--h))  93.3%,
    calc(0.134*var(--h))  75%);
}

body{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
```

```html
<a class="p-button" href="">Explore The Tech</a>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68508682/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>